# How to get a discord bot to give a user a certain role if they DM the bot a passphrase discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that looks for a passphrase in the DMs it gets, then gives the user a role in my server if the passphrase is in the message.  The code below runs without error, but the user doesn't get the role specified in `role`.

```
    if message.guild is None:
        if passphrase in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")

            serv = client.get_guild(0000000000000000)
            role = serv.get_role(0000000000000000000)
            member = serv.get_member(message.author.id)
            if member in serv.members:
                await member.add_roles(role, reason="Member was verified via DMs.")
                await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`guild.get_member()` is an `Optional[Member]` return, as [per the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member). It's entirely possible that this is causing the issue. Instead, use [`await guild.fetch_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_role#discord.Guild.fetch_member), as it will work regardless of whether or not you have a member cache and member intents enabled in the Developer Portal.

If you want to use `get_member()`, make sure that you are passing the proper intents to your bot in order to get a list of members from the guild, and make sure that the intents are enabled in the developer portal.